# Перенаправить TCP запросы на локальный сокет

Tags: python, windows, tcp

У меня есть программа, которая отсылает последовательность TCP запросов на IP адрес, допустим x.x.x.x и на порт, например, 8124. У меня есть настроенный локальный сокет на питоне на этом же порте, который будет отвечать на эти запросы так, как нужно программе, чтобы она работала. Задача, думаю, уже ясна - нужно любыми средствами (внутри windows) перенаправить запросы с x.x.x.x:8124 на localhost:8124.

Уже пробовал через файл hosts, также пробовал командой *netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=x.x.x.x listenport=8124 connectaddress=localhost connectport=8124*, а также через *route add*, но не совсем разобрался с синтаксисом в обоих случаях, так что мог нахимичить.

Буду рад любой помощи

## UPD

Получилось сделать перенаправление через route add x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 y.y.y.y, где y.y.y.y - локальный IP, но теперь программа не хочет работать (через ProcMon видно, что программа постоянно переподключается к самой себе)[image: скрин из procmon]. Попробую запустить сокет на другом ПК

## UPD2

Запустил сокет на другом пк, однако винда не желает перекидывать запросы на другой IP, их получает локальный сокет (несмотря на то что *route* я перенаправил). В ProcMone все та же картина

Answer (score 2):

Ага, не Linux, а Windows, значит сделать чуть посложнее. Можно воспользоваться сторонними утилитами. Мне, для нужд разработки сервиса, в свое время понадобилось что-то подобное. Пользовался вот этим (бесплатно):
[RelayTCP](http://www.dlcsistemas.com/html/relay_tcp.html)

Недавно сталкивался с другой утилитой уже на гите: [Yaxy -- это proxy-сервер для веб-разработчика, подменяющий запрашиваемые ресурсы, следуя простым правилам](https://github.com/Kolyaj/Yaxy/blob/master/readme_ru.md)

Но вроде бы Вам нужно пользоваться только встроенными средствами системы? Тогда забудьте о route, не сработает. Нужен **netsh**. 
Синтаксис команды следующий:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localaddress listenport=localport connectaddress=destaddress connectport=destport
где,

```
listenaddress – локальный  адрес, на котором будет ожидаться соединение
listenport – локальный порт, который должен слушаться (на него ожидается соединение)
connectaddress – ip-адрес / dns-имя, на который будет перенаправляться соединение
connectport – TPC порт, на который перенаправляется соединение с порта listenport
```

Запускаем оболочку с админовскими правами и выполняем, к примеру:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3300 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=4400 connectaddress=10.10.1.110

С помощью netstat проверяем:

netstat -ano | findstr :3300

Видим: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И даже можем теперь проверить, кто же слушает этот порт:

tasklist | findstr 1124 (PID процесса - из скриншота).

Но! Необходимо удостовериться, что брандмаэур "не против" таких переадресаций. Если стоит стандартный брандмауэер, его можно "попросить" разрешить с помощью команды **netsh advfirewall firewall add rule**

Ну, и из полезного: команда **netsh interface portproxy show all** выведет весь список созданных нами перенаправлений.

Comment: удалять все перенаправления или одиночно выборочно тоже можно: netsh interface portproxy reset очистит все, а netsh interface portproxy delete  - выборочно

Comment: Подумал и решил добавить: 127.0.0.1 использовать в качестве обозначения локального компьютера некорректно. Следует использовать 0.0.0.0

Comment: Наверное, все-таки listenaddress=10.10.1.110, а connectaddress=127.0.0.1? Кстати, portproxy  так вообще умеет делать?

Comment: Пример приводил для редиректа с локального порта на внешний. Если наоборот, с внешнего на локальный, то да, именно так. Да, вполне редиректит TCP, с UDP, увы, так не получится. Можно и с внешнего на внешний делать.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, однако я не совсем понял, как именно мне нужно сформулировать *netsh* запрос чтобы он работал по условиям моей задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Если вас устраивает перехват *всего* трафика на некоторых адрес, а не только на определенный порт - можно схитрить и добавить дополнительный адрес своему компьютеру. Достоинство решения - все можно сделать через графический интерфейс, недостаток же - можно случайно сломать себе интернет если винда почему-то подумает что этот адрес отлично подойдет в качестве адреса отправителя для исходящих пакетов.

На Windows X дополнительный адрес добавляется как на скриншоте ниже, на других версиях шаги могут быть другими. Тут надо сначала добраться до настроек адаптера, а дальше интерфейс не менялся со времен Windows XP (за 2000 не поручусь - не видел).

[image]

Если у вы свой адрес получили по DHCP, то так просто еще один адрес не добавить.
Можно временно переключиться на ручной адрес вписав текущие полученные по DHCP настройки. Или же можно воспользоваться loopback-адаптером. Для этого зайдите в диспетчер устройств, там выберите установку (старого) устройства, в открывшемся мастере откажитесь от автоматической установки в пользу ручного выбора:

[image]

Далее выберите тип "сетевые адаптеры", изготовитель "Microsoft", в модели должно быть написано про "адаптер замыкания на себя".

После этого появится новый сетевой интерфейс, которому можно назначить произвольный сетевой адрес.

Также можно воспользоваться loopback-адаптером если хочется иметь возможность быстро выключать и выключать перехват трафика.