# Перенаправить запросы от приложения на localhost (Windows)

Tags: windows, http, hosts

Помогите перенаправить запросы от приложения на локальный сервер.
Приложение делает http запрос в стиле `http://0.0.0.0/query.php`

Редактирование hosts файла:

```
127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0
```

не дает результатов..

Comment: Fiddler > AutoResponder...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747236/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-tcp-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82/747473#747473